# Counterexample to $H_n(X)\oplus H_n(X)\cong H_n(X\vee X)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

By homology I mean singular homology with coefficients in $\mathbb Z$.

Let $(X,x_0)$ be a based space. It is well known that $H_n(X)\oplus H_n(X)\cong H_n(X\vee X)$ if $X$ is nondegenerately based. Is there a counterexample when this condition doesn't hold?

Comment: I suspect the Hawaiian earring is a counterexample, though it seems difficult to prove.

Comment: This is not true for $n=0$, unless you meant reduced homology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X= C\mathcal{H}$ be the cone on the Hawaiian earring $\mathcal{H}$. Then $H_1(X\vee X)$ is uncountable according to Theorem 2.6 in [this paper](http://www.math.byu.edu/~conner/research/he_main.pdf). Here the wedge sum is formed at the interesting points.

Comment: Nice, that seems to work. I'm still interested in $n\geq 2$.

Comment: Take suspensions to get an example for any $n\geq 2$. Note that suspension commutes with wedge and with cone (it commutes with colimits in general).